# Django ошибка ['Значение “search” не является верным UUID-ом.']

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, исключения, url

Создаю поисковую GET-форму в Django, не работает url привязка и выдаёт странную ошибку:

```
ValidationError at /youtube/search/
['Значение “search” не является верным UUID-ом.']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/youtube/search/?query=12345678912345678912345678912345
Django Version: 3.1
Exception Type: ValidationError
Exception Value:    
['Значение “search” не является верным UUID-ом.']
```

Вот основные файлы:

```
# urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_view, name='home'),

    path('<str:identifier>/', views.video_view, name='video'),
    path('<str:identifier>/leave_comment', views.leave_comment_view, name='leave_comment'),

    path('search/', views.find_query_view, name='search_results'),
]
```

```
# models.py
import uuid
from django.db import models


class Video(models.Model):
    id          = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    author      = models.CharField('Author', max_length=30)
    name        = models.CharField('Video title', max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField('Video description', blank=True, null=True, max_length=500)
```

```
# Сама форма

<form action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Search...">
</form>
```

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db.models import Q
from .models import Video


def find_query_view(request):
    f = request.GET['query']
    response = Video.objects.filter(
        Q(author__icontains=f) | Q(name__icontains=f) | Q(description__icontains=f)
    )
    return render(request, 'youtube/search.html', {'searching_query': f, 'response': response})
```

Любая помощь, даже в виде "используй специальную библиотеку" приветствуется

P.S. Ненужную часть кода удалил, ибо очень много всего получается

Comment: у тебя точно больше  нет ничего в urls.py? у тебя идет mapping в `youtube/search`, вместо `/search`, покажи весь код

Comment: Обновил описание файлов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переместите роут `search/` выше. Джанга устроена так, что ищет совпадение ссылки по порядку, сверху вниз.

```
# urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_view, name='home'),

    # сюда:
    path('search/', views.find_query_view, name='search_results'),

    path('<str:identifier>/', views.video_view, name='video'),
    path('<str:identifier>/leave_comment', views.leave_comment_view, name='leave_comment'),

    # path('search/', views.find_query_view, name='search_results'),
]
```

P.S. для UUID можно в шаблонах ссылок использовать `<uuid:identifier>/`. [Подробнее...](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters)

Comment: Спасибо большое, мне помогло!